# Thunderbird mail on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: email

I'm switching from an old phone and need to know if I can install Thunderbird on a Samsung S3 or any other similar phone? I have several business emails and like the way Thunderbird works.

Being new to this, if I can't put TBird on the Samsung or similar product, then what type of e-mail platform will I be using?

Comment: Please clarify what e-mail provider you're using. Thunderbird is the client, but Thunderbird isn't the company that is hosting your e-mail service. Are you connecting to corporate e-mail servers?

Answer (score 4):

Mozilla have not created a Thunderbird app, so you're not going to have that option.

That said, there are **dozens** (or more) [email apps in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=email). (Not to mention the stock email app that ships with the device.) A large number of them can handle multiple email accounts just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have Thunderbird installed on my S3 phone.

Comment: Oh? Care to share a link?